# pydoc-like program to browse content/code of Python files in a browser?

Tags: python, pydoc

pydoc allows me to view documentation of Python modules and packages in directories added to my PYTHONPATH in a browser. Is there a way to browse the complete code of those files?

I converted Edoardo Ivanec's code using [3to2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/3to2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import with_statement
import CGIHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer, BaseHTTPServer
import os  
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
from io import open

class SourceViewer(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        path = os.path.join(os.getcwdu(), self.path[1:])
        if os.path.exists(path) and path.endswith(u'.py'):
            with open(path) as file:
                code = file.read()
                hl = highlight(code, PythonLexer(), HtmlFormatter(noclasses=True, linenos=u'table'))
                self.send_response(200)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(str(hl).encode('UTF-8'))
                return
        else:       
            super(self.__class__, self).do_GET()


if __name__ == u"__main__":
    server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((u'localhost', 8080), SourceViewer)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Going to `localhost:8080` shows a `no data received` message. How should I feed it data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the HTTP server in the standard library with the help of [pygments](http://pygments.org/) to serve a highlighted and line-numbered version of the Python source files in a directory.

This is an example for Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import http.server
import os  
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter

class SourceViewer(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.path[1:])
        if os.path.exists(path) and path.endswith('.py'):
            with open(path) as file:
                code = file.read()
                hl = highlight(code, PythonLexer(), HtmlFormatter(noclasses=True, linenos='table'))
                self.send_response(200)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(bytes(hl, 'UTF-8'))
                return
        else:       
            super().do_GET()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = http.server.HTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), SourceViewer)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Python 2, based in your 3to2 conversion:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import with_statement
import SimpleHTTPServer, BaseHTTPServer
import os  
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter

class SourceViewer(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        path = os.path.join(os.getcwdu(), self.path[1:])
        if os.path.exists(path) and path.endswith(u'.py'):
            with open(path) as file:
                code = file.read()
                hl = highlight(code, PythonLexer(), HtmlFormatter(noclasses=True, linenos=u'table'))
                self.send_response(200)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(hl)
                return
        else:    
            SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

if __name__ == u"__main__":
    server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((u'localhost', 8080), SourceViewer)
    server.serve_forever()
```

And the example result:

[image: Example result]

Comment: Hey Eduardo! I converted the code using `3to2`.(see edited original post.) However, I get a `no data received` message, how should I pass the data?

Comment: That's too bad - I'll try it when I get home in a couple of minutes.

Comment: It seems the `super()` call to SimpleHTTPRequestHandler was failing - it may be because it's an old-style class, although that seems strange and I didn't really check. Please see the new version in the edit, it works with the explicit call to the parent class.

Comment: Wow, superb! Is it possible to adjust it to let it check `/usr/lib/python2.7` and `usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` as well?

Comment: If on a pinch I would just create a new directory full of symlinks to all interesting source locations. It should work.

Comment: You could also add an 'elif' that tries to import the required name as a module (using `__import__`). If it works you can then use `modulename.__file__` to find out the filename you have to open to show its source. But that wouldn't help with actually listing the available modules. You would have to use something like pkgutil (http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules) for that.